# Terminate from loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class CommaSepratedNumMax 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner san = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Integer> Al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String line;
        String[] lineVector;
        System.out.println("enter the series");
        line = san.nextLine();
        lineVector = line.split(",");
        for(int i=0;;i++)
        {
            Al.add(i,Integer.parseInt(lineVector[i]));
        }

        int max=Al.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<Al.size();i++)
        {
            if (Al.get(i)>max)
                max=Al.get(i);
        } 
        System.out.println("max no in series is="+max);
    }
}
```

I want to terminate loop when the number is not left in comma separated string but i did not find the condition...

Comment: Use the `break` statement.

Comment: What conditions have you tried before?

Comment: This code will die a horrible death with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`: `for(int i=0;;i++)` loops until `lineVector[i]` dies.

Comment: @cyberPheonix - OP is asking for condition to the first loop. Plus as per your logic, if `Al.get(1) > Al.get(0)` the loop is exited without testing the remaining elements. OP's program is designed to find the max value in the entire set

Comment: @afrin216 - my bad, it was indeed wrong, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your loop like this, nothing else required

for(int i=0;i< lineVector.length;i++)

Answer (score 0):

When you use split() function, it populates your String array with elements seperated by '-'. Like, "i-am-doing-good" will be assigned as lineVector[0]=i, lineVector[1]=am, lineVector[2]=doing and so on. So, if you use

```
for(int i=0;i<=lineVector.length;i++)
    {
        Al.add(i,Integer.parseInt(lineVector[i]));
    }
```

here the break point will be that String array length which is a normal scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) and do away with the loop condition itself. Plus you avoid all the counting indexes stuff - very messy. Its available from `Java 5` I believe

```
for(String input:lineVector)
{
    Al.add(i,Integer.parseInt(input));
}
```